# How exactly do the Gunslinger Crits work?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

I see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106499/how-exactly-does-the-gunslinger-work) that Gunslinger crits are every 3 consecutive hits. But what is that more clarified? Does it mean that you must hold the attack button down, and have three attacks hit an enemy (in a row), or can you hit an enemy 2 times, then stop attacking, then melee again for a crit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote directly off the wiki:

> ...the player is able to perform a three-part combo attack on enemies. Should an enemy be hit three times in succession, the third strike (a downward motion with a clenched fist) will become an automatic critical hit. This does not need to be performed on a single enemy, but the attack key cannot be released during the combo or it will be lost and reset.

As far as I'm aware, the important part is that you are hitting an enemy, a teammate, or a building. So what you could do is be hitting your dispenser two times, then if you flick your mouse over to an enemy quickly enough, hit them the third time for the crit. If you want to test this more yourself, look for that downward attack every third hit. If the downward animation happens, the attack is a crit if it hits an enemy.

Comment: So, each enemy hit while the button is held down factors to the combo?

Comment: Yes, you have to keep holding the attack button and not miss any of the hits. If you hit twice and stop, no critical. If you hit once and miss the second you also won't get a crit.

Comment: So, for an example, if I hit an enemy 2 times, they die on the second, and I keep the button held down, the crit will happen when I hit an enemy?

Comment: Yes, it will crit the next time you hit someone as long as you keep attacking.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can still "store" crits by swapping weapons then swapping back.

Comment: I'll test this when I have the opportunity to actually play tf2.

Comment: I played for a bit and you have to constantly be attacking, not letting off the attack button, to get the crit on the third attack. For example, if you hit someone twice with melee and wait at all, the third hit will be normal unless it's simply a random crit. Now that I think of it, I didn't try going from melee to primary or secondary after a second hit while still holding left click, then attacking with melee, but I'm pretty sure that wouldn't cause a crit.